# Gabor Filter Parameter

Tags: matlab, gabor

I am doing research on images using gabor filter. 
I have read the following post:

[Apply a Gabor filter to an input image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/apply-a-gabor-filter-to-an-input-image)

There must be some formula to determine the value for gamma,sigma,lambda,psi...can i know how to determine it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best values for these parameters depend on your application. You should probably try different values on a validation set to find out which ones work best for you.

Comment: I am using it for feature extraction of finger vein and finger knuckle.

Comment: The lambda parameter sets the wavelength of your gabor filter. It's value depends on the width of what you're interested in.

Comment: I am using Matlab to do feature extraction of finger vein and finger knuckle.

gb= exp(-.5*(x_theta.^2/sigma_x^2+y_theta.^2   /sigma_y^2)).*cos(2*pi*x_theta*f)

From my understanding,
sigma=sigma = lambda/pi*sqrt(log(2)/2)*(2^bw+1)/(2^bw-1);
sigma_x = sigma;
sigma_y = sigma/gamma;

What are the suitable value for lambda,gamma,and bw?

I am not quite understand about the width, can explain in detail?